# How to update react-select-plus value via parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have the following react-select-plus component inside the parent component.

```
<Select
onCloseResetsInput={false}
onBlurResetsInput={false}
ref={(select) => {this.select = select;}}
value={this.state.searchValue}
filterOptions={false}
onInputKeyDown={this.onInputKeyDown}
instanceId="search"
className="improved-search"
name="form-field-name"
clearable={false}
placeholder="search"
searchPromptText="search"
onBlurResetsInput={false}
noResultsText="no results"
scrollMenuIntoView={false}
arrowRenderer={this.arrowRenderer}
isLoading={this.state.searchIsLoading}
options={this.state.searchOptions}
onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
onChange={this.selectEvent}
autoBlur={true}
/>
```

What I would like to do is to update/clear the input value in the parent component's componentWillReceiveProps method, like so:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if (newProps.location.pathname.indexOf('q=') === -1) {
        this.setState({
            searchValue: null
        })
    }   
}
```

React-select-plus is claiming to be a controlled component but at least in my case updating the parent components state (i.e. this.state.searchValue, which is passed as the "value" prop to react-select-plus) does not update the input of the Select component. Looking at the source of Select.js from GitHub the component does not update the value inside its own componentWillReceiveProps.

Am I missing something here or does some of my own methods override the input updating for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the value and onChange of React-Select a bit differently.

Lets consider your object to store form_data in State/Redux looks like this:

```
form: {saving: false, data: {} };
// data object contain field values in format {name: value}
```

Consider you have an onChnage handler similar to this:

```
const onChange = e => {
    /**
     * A general purpose onChange handler for inputs.
     * @param   {Object} e      The onChange event of input.
     * @return  {Object}        An Object containing name and value of the event target.
     */
    return {
        name: e.target.name,
        value: e.target.type === 'checkbox' ? e.target.checked : e.target.value,
    };
    // Put the value it's returning in your state/redux store, depending on your application
};
```

Now considering the name of your input is `mySelect`, then your React-Select component should be like this:

```
const OPTIONS = ['option1, option2', ...];

<Select
    isDisabled={form.saving} // disable it if form is saving
    id='id_mySelect'
    name='mySelect'
    label='My Select'
    {/* if your state/redux store has a value for it, then set its value to correct option
    NOTICE: It requires an object in proper format
    else leave it empty */}
    value={
        form.data.mySelect ?
        { label: form.data.mySelect, value: form.data.mySelect }
        :
        null
    }

    {/* See below for explanation of onChange */}
    onChange={(option, event) => {
        // console.log({option, event});
        let value='';
        {/* If react select is being cleared then value is empty string
        otherwise its the value of selected option */}
        if(event.action!=='clear')
            value = option.value;
        return onChange({target: {name: 'mySelect', value: value}});
    }}
    options={OPTIONS.map(x => ({label: x, value: x}))}
    placeholder='My Select'
    isClearable
/>
```

**Why this weird onChange in React-Select:**

Usually `onChange` of an input you get an js event object which contains information about the event, target etc. We use `event.target` to get its name and value.

But `onChange` of React-Select component it gives two object, lets call them `option` and `event`.
Add `console.log({option, event})` in first line of anon function in onChnage of react select to see them yourself.

**option** object looks like this:

```
{ label: 'selected_options_label' value: 'selected_options_value' }
```

**event** object looks like this:

```
{
    action: 'select-option',  // its value is 'select-option' or 'clear'
    options: undefined  // its always undefined, not sure why
}
```

Since in our onChange handler we are expecting an event object similar to this:

```
{
    ...
    target: {
        ...
        name: 'target_name',
        value: 'target_value'
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

But React-Select doesn't gives and event object like this, so we need to make an object ourselves which has all the stuff our `onChange` handler excepts. Therefore in onChange of React-Select we make an anonymous function which makes an object in required format which contains name and value and then call our onChange handler with that data, so that proper value will get saved in state/store.